# How to use conn.read() to read a banner

Tags: go

I'm using Go to connect to a random port. Let's assume it's 22 because that's a good example. Some ports have a banner, and some don't.

I'm trying to get the banner that shows up immediately after I connect to the port. In this case `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9` but the code below doesn't really give me anything and no error.

I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong here.

```
    banner := make([]byte, 0, 256)

    connStr := net.JoinHostPort(host, port);

    dialer := net.Dialer{Timeout: 3 * time.Second}

    conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", connStr)
            if err != nil {
                io.WriteString(w,err.Error())
            } else {
                n, err := conn.Read(banner);
                if err != nil {
                    log.Println(w, "read error: %v", err)
                }   
                log.Println(string(banner))
                io.WriteString(w, "Connected to " +  connStr + ". " + string(n) + " byte output:" + string(banner))
                defer conn.Close()
            }
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? Or do I have to send something in order to get the banner?

Comment: What do you mean by "a banner"? What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @adrian, i'm trying to see what data comes back when i connect to a port. For example: telnet server 22. Usually you'll get "OpenSSH..." as the banner. I'm trying to capture that banner IF it exists.

Comment: Try reading it via bufio.Reader.ReadString('\n') to read until you see a newline. You don't know how much you're going to read, you need some sort of delimiter to stop reading.

Comment: Your banner has len 0 so nothing will be read ever.

Comment: @Volker you got it! my mistake! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on what a banner is.

If the banner is delimited by a distinguished byte, then use bufio.Reader to slurp up bytes to that delimiter.  Set a deadline in case the server does not respond.

```
conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", connStr)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer conn.Close()
conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second))
br := bufio.NewReader(conn)
banner, err := bf.ReadBytes(delim)
if err != nil {
     // handle error
}
```

If the banner is not delimited in some way, then read until a timeout:

```
conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", connStr)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer conn.Close()

// Read for one second or until 256 bytes are read.
conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second))
banner := make([]byte, 256)
n, err := io.ReadFull(banner)
banner = banner[:n]
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. Sorry about the delays in my reply. I will mark your answer correct shortly after i test.

Comment: turns out my issue was the byte slice was of len 0. It was a typo on my part.

Comment: @anoopb That's one issue.  The other issue is that the code incorrectly assumes that the banner will banner will be read in a single call to Read.